# how can i integrate this integrand?(solid angle of circular loop)

Tags: integration, solid-angle

hi i`m solving some electrodynamics problem but i`m troubled with integration.
i don`t know how to integrate this integrand analytically.
what i want to integrate is this(posted picture)
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpOOE.png)

this equation is originated from definition of solid angle; d(omega)=da/r^2
i chose primed notation for the source point(on the circular loop which has radius a) and not primed notation for the observation point(any point except on the circular loop).
radius of loop is a so i integrate r' from 0 to a and because of circular loop, azimutahl angle is o to 2pi

thank you for reading my question

Comment: The apostrophe is the ' key. The back tick is the ` key. Use the apostrophe for _I'm_ and use the back tick to `format code`. This site uses MathJax formatting. Tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Where is your work? Can you draw a a figure showing all angles? What does the integral denote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integral in the picture was
$$\begin{align}I&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^a\frac{r^{\prime}}{\left(r^{\prime}\cos\phi^{\prime}-r\sin\theta\cos\phi\right)^2+\left(r^{\prime}\sin\phi^{\prime}-r\sin\theta\sin\phi\right)^2+r^2\cos^2\theta}dr^{\prime}\,d\phi^{\prime}\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^a\frac{r^{\prime}}{{r^{\prime}}^2-2rr^{\prime}\sin\theta\cos\left(\phi^{\prime}-\phi\right)+r^2}dr^{\prime}\,d\phi^{\prime}\\
&=\int_0^a\frac{r^{\prime}}{{r^{\prime}}^2+r^2}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{d\phi^{\prime}}{1-\frac{2rr^{\prime}\sin\theta}{{r^{\prime}}^2+r^2}\cos\left(\phi^{\prime}-\phi\right)}dr^{\prime}\end{align}$$
To simplify the azimuthal integral we let $e=\frac{2rr^{\prime}\sin\theta}{{r^{\prime}}^2+r^2}$ and $\phi^{\prime}-\phi=\nu+\pi$ and then we can use the eccentric anomaly
$$\sin E=\frac{\sqrt{1-e^2}\sin\nu}{1+e\cos\nu},\,\cos E=\frac{\cos\nu+e}{1+e\cos\nu},\,dE=\frac{\sqrt{1-e^2}d\nu}{1+e\cos\nu}$$
So we get
$$\begin{align}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{d\phi^{\prime}}{1-\frac{2rr^{\prime}\sin\theta}{{r^{\prime}}^2+r^2}\cos\left(\phi^{\prime}-\phi\right)}&=\int_{-\pi-\phi}^{\pi-\phi}\frac{d\nu}{1+e\cos\nu}=\int_{\nu=-\pi-\phi}^{\nu=\pi-\phi}\frac{dE}{\sqrt{1-e^2}}\\
&=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{1-e^2}}=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{1-\frac{4r^2{r^{\prime}}^2\sin^2\theta}{\left({r^{\prime}}^2+r^2\right)^2}}}\end{align}$$
And now we are back to
$$\begin{align}I&=2\pi\int_0^a\frac{r^{\prime}dr^{\prime}}{\sqrt{{r^{\prime}}^4+2r^2{r^{\prime}}^2+r^4-4r^2{r^{\prime}}^2\sin^2\theta}}\\
&=2\pi\int_0^a\frac{r^{\prime}dr^{\prime}}{\sqrt{\left({r^{\prime}}^2+r^2-2r^2\sin^2\theta\right)^2+4r^4\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta}}\\
&=2\pi\int_0^a\frac{r^{\prime}dr^{\prime}}{\sqrt{\left({r^{\prime}}^2+r^2\cos2\theta\right)^2+r^4\sin^22\theta}}\\
&=\pi\int_{\sinh^{-1}\frac{r^2\cos2\theta}{r^2\sin2\theta}}^{\sinh^{-1}\frac{a^2+r^2\cos2\theta}{r^2\sin2\theta}}\frac{r^2\sin2\theta\cosh u\,du}{r^2\sin2\theta\cosh u}\\
&=\pi\sinh^{-1}\frac{a^2+r^2\cos2\theta}{r^2\sin2\theta}-\pi\sinh^{-1}\frac{r^2\cos2\theta}{r^2\sin2\theta}\\
&=\pi\ln\left(\frac{a^2+r^2\cos2\theta+\sqrt{(a^2+r^2\cos2\theta)^2+r^4\sin^22\theta}}{r^2\cos2\theta+\sqrt{r^4\cos^22\theta+r^4\sin^22\theta}}\right)\\
&=\pi\ln\left(\frac{a^2+r^2\cos2\theta+\sqrt{a^4+2a^2r^2\cos2\theta+r^4}}{r^2+r^2\cos2\theta}\right)\end{align}$$
Where we have made the substitution
$${r^{\prime}}^2+r^2\cos2\theta=r^2\sin2\theta\sinh u$$
**EDIT**: Had some serious errors in my first version; hope this one is better.

Comment: thank you for your help i had thought this problem 2 days because of integration. thank you so much